# VCC to ground confusion

Tags: ground, short-circuit, atmega328p, vcc, schematic

I recently reached out for help about uploading Arduino code to a pcb I designed for an LED watch. It was pointed out that I had a couple of errors in my circuit design:
*“First, R9 should be a pullup to VCC, not inline with the reset signal. And secondly, which is the biggest error: you have connected VCC directly to GND. Follow the net from the ATMega's VCC pins off to the right then down - it goes straight to ground.”*

[image: LED watch schematic]

My questions are:

1. Do I move R9 (10K resistor) between VCC and the real time clock (as the arrows indicates)?
   [image: Moving resistor]
2. How do I fix the VCC to GND error? To be honest, I don’t fully understand the problem because VCC is connected to GND in other places in the schematic.

Thanks,
Dylan

Edit for clarification:
Isnt VCC connected to ground here as well?
[image: VCC to ground?]

Comment: 1. R9 goes between /rst and vcc. 2. Remove the gnd symbol on the bottom right of the rtc chip. Gnd does not connect to vcc!

Comment: Thank you very much. Just to be clear (as I’ll need to order new pcbs), am I adding a connection (and R9) between /rst on the RTC and VCC (while keeping the connection between /rst on RTC and /rst on Atmega)?

Comment: What were you trying to achieve by connecting VCC to GND? This is the very definition of a short circuit. Thinking more about this may help you fix some fundamental misconceptions.

Comment: VSS is almost always 'ground'.   I've seen thousands of schemes and VSS  is always tied to ground..   You wiill never see it connected to VCC (if the schematic was drawn by a real engineer).   If you're curious where VCC VDD etc come from, they are leftovers from the early days of battery operated vacuum tube.  They would have multiple different batteries, named 'A', 'B'  etc...

Comment: To your last update, no, VCC goes to one side of capacitor, GND goes to other side of capacitor. VCC and GND are not shorted together at the capacitor, and they must not be shorted anywhere else either, or there can't be a voltage difference between them.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short circuit is due to the VCC line being directly connected to GND. By removing the GND flag you can fix this. R9 should be moved so that it connects VCC with the RST line through the resistor. So one end of R9 should be connected to VCC, the other end to the RST pin.
[image]